# Avoid memory leak when using array element in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, memory-leaks

```
NSString *hostStr2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@/getplaylist.php?ip=%@",yourip,restip];
NSLog(@"XMLAppDelegate checkstatusthread call to php for status,playlist and nowplaying XML's %@" ,hostStr2);
NSData *dataURL2 =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr2 ]];  
[hostStr2 release];

NSString *playlistdata=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSArray *ipItemsArray;

// memory leak showing at below line    
ipItemsArray =[playlistdata componentsSeparatedByString:@"|^|"];

[playlistdata release];
```

What I am storing in **ipItemsArray** is a big XML data separated with a delimiter '|^|'.
The problem is when i run this it is giving memory leaks in this array.
Is there any other type of array that we can use or can someone better optimize this code so  that i can get rid of the memory leaks happening.

Comment: What makes you think that line is leaking? What tool have you used? I can't see any memory leaks in this code, the line in question is creating an autoreleased array.

Comment: Agree with the above. The code is fine, but if ipItemsArray is an IVAR you want to keep around, you need to retain it when you create the autoreleased array.

Comment: In XCode under Profile I used the tool to find the leaks called Leaks. When i run this under this profile  it shows memory leak at the above line code. btw this only works when we connect it to an iPhone and use this analyze tool.

Answer (score -1):

better to allocate memory to that array.And release it in the dealloc a method

Comment: I don't think this will work better with the kind of application that i am developing because it stores two XML's and requires large or sometimes small size. Anyway thanks.